# How to get all file paths while using html "file" input with multiple attribute

Tags: java, javascript, html

I am developing a web page in which I have to upload multiple files on
a single browse.

I am using html `<input id="filelist" type="file" multiple=multiple>`

This enables the multiple file selection and also retrieves the 
full file path of all the selected file, which shows in file 
upload text area.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    <!--
    function showname(){    
        var  filepath = document.form1.filelist.value ;  
        alert(filepath); //this shows only first filename among selected file
    }
    -->
    </script>
```

But the problem is when I get the value of input, it returns only the first file
name among selected files.

Now how can I get the file paths which is shown in file upload text area.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is browser specific.  So you might be running this in a browser that doesn't support this.  For example Firefox does. Here's an example of how to use this feature:

http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/12/multiple-file-input-in-firefox-3-6/

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using http://www.uploadify.com/about/ or http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/. They should help you out, and also add some cool features to your file upload form.

Answer (score 0):

File paths are deliberately hidden from the page for security purposes. To look at the local filesystem you need to use Java, Active-x (meh), or Flash.

Comment: You're quite right, but this doesn't address the OP's question.